# Changing the value of event in CardService.newTextInput does not change the displayed value in textinput in gmail addon

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I have simple gmail addon in which i am trying to make custom login form. The problem i am facing is that when i am changing the input field from on Change handler the displayed value is not changing . Trying to hide the password field.

**Textinput widget**

```
function getMembersSelectMenu(){

   var textInput = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("Password")
    .setTitle("Password")
    .setHint("Enter Password")
    .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName("handlePasswordChange"))


return textInput;

}
```

**handler function for textInput**

```
function handlePasswordChange(e){
 // e.formInput.pass = e.formInput.Password;
  e.formInput.Password = "*";
  e.formInputs.Password = "******"
  Logger.log("my value object" + JSON.stringify(e));

}
```

Already checked the object and value is updated but not change in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `textInput` field value is change, `handlePasswordChange` is called with `eventObject`. I think you're trying to set the value in that `eventObject` inside `handlePasswordChange` and not on that field.

I think we can do something like this :

1.Create some global variable to keep track of field.

2.Create field and assign in that variable.

3.On value change set value in that.

```
var passwordField;

function getMembersSelectMenu(){
     passwordField = CardService.newTextInput()
        .setFieldName("Password")
        .setTitle("Password")
        .setHint("Enter Password")
        .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName("handlePasswordChange"))
    return passwordField;
}

function handlePasswordChange(e){
    // e.formInput.pass = e.formInput.Password;
    passwordField.setValue("*******");
}
```

Comment: can we declare the global variable directly? what is the scope for it because we do not have classes in appscript please tell me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes @TalhaFayyaz we can declare global variables.

Comment: can we please tell me the sequence from which it is executed ? i am beginner to app Script

Comment: Maybe you can ask that as a new question ?